# Passing parameters to msi without msiexec.

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I'm trying pass some parameters to an MSI from bootstrapper. Because I need MSI be able to display UI, but in basic varitant (/qb). At the moment I'm doing it the following way:

```
<ExePackage Id="Drv" DisplayName="Drv" SourceFile="..\redist\msiexec.exe" InstallCommand="/i setup.msi /qb>
  <Payload SourceFile="setup.msi"/>
</ExePackage>
```

But I'd like not to take msiexec inside bootstrapper and do something like this:

```
<MsiPackage Id="Drv" SourceFile="setup.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes">
  <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArg" Value="/qb"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

Is it possible to pass parameters to a msi without msiexec.exe?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Showing UI is nothing to do with passing parameters, so maybe you have an incorrect assumption about the way some of this works? You can still pass properties on the command line even if it's a silent-ish install.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
The problem is, when I use <MsiPackage...> with DisplayInternalUI set to "yes", I get full UI. While I need basic UI, as if I run "setup.msi /qb" or "msiexec.exe /i setup.msi /qb" from command line. So the question is, if it is possible to pass that "/qb" parameter to <MsiPackage...>?

Comment: If you own the MSI and don't need a full UI at all, you can use a minimal UI that's much closer to /qb.

Comment: so, what's wrong with the "and do something like this"? Are you using wix >=3.7?

Comment: @TomBlodget As far as I'm concerned there will be no UI shown if ShowInternalUI is set to "no", otherwise if it is set to "yes" full UI is shown.

Comment: @TomBlodget Unfortunatelly this MSI is not my own.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa I'm using wix 3.8.
Looks like CommandLineArg set to "/qb" has no effect, just as if it were set to "/qf"

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa I've found the solution. Thanks for comments

Comment: I know this isn't constructive but it seems super wacko that setup exe's don't just take the exact same set of arguments as msi's. Anyone know why they're even slightly different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution.
I opened the setup.msi with Orca. Added two properties LIMITUI and ARPNOMODIFY and set them to 1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , http://fdo-workspace.blogspot.ru/2009/10/use-orca-modify-msi-add-mst-and.html)

In Bundle.wxs I have:

```
<MsiPackage Id="Drv" SourceFile="setup.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"/>
```

Setting LIMITUI to 1 is similiar to "/qb" in command line.